# swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb)from email -in my code?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type, unwrap

This is my code here found the fatal error.i try to solve this problem but lot of times it shows,and it shows the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

```
import UIKit
class VerifyProfileViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,FBLoginViewDelegate {
    var liveurl = demo_url

    @IBOutlet weak var f_name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var l_name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email_id: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobilenumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        var mobile_Number = mobilenumber.text
        var email_Address = email_id.text
        var first_name = f_name.text 
        var last_name = l_name.text
        var email1 = isValidEmail(email_Address)
        let email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_email") as NSString
        println("The email :\(email)")
        let first_name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_name") as NSString
        println("The firstname :\(first_name)")

        let last_name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_lname") as NSString
        println("The firstname :\(last_name)")
        //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(facebookid, forKey:"id")
        //let facebook_id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_id")! as NSString
        //println("The fbID :\(facebook_id)")
        email_id.text = email
        f_name.text = first_name
        l_name.text = last_name
```

Comment: It's probably nil, check before unwrapping it.

Comment: i sent my full code so please check and specify my mistake

Comment: @B.Saravana Kumar I think you should start it over. BTW Swift is a type inferred language. Give it a try. When Swift coding you should always use String instead of NSString. Array instead of NSArray and while using numbers you should use Int or Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("abc@def.com", forKey: "fb_email")
if let email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("fb_email") {
    println(email)
}
```

Comment: Impossible to do not work. You have to show your code otherwise will be impossible to help you

Comment: how to show my code?here unable to display using stackoverflow

Comment: Just to let you know that email has no value outside the brackets.

Comment: Here i used the NSUserdefaults so it can make the crash?

Comment: Any other solution for this bug?

Comment: how to post the code?If u give your mail id i will send the code via mail.

Comment: First of all Swift is a type inferred language. It means you don't need to specify the type most of the time. You should always use String instead of NSString. You are naming your vars starting with capital letters and Swift convention is to name it starting with a  lowercase letter. The same applies to your functions naming.

Comment: Once you fix everything that I mentioned I can read your code.

Comment: i made the changes so please check and specify my mistakes?

Comment: Edit your original code using Xcode and once you finished you can post it here. When posting it here using the code format you have to  paste your code, select the exact lines of code and then after that you can press control-k at your keyboard to format is as code.

Comment: Don't post your whole code. Post only what's related to your problem.

Comment: I post the corresponding code it had make unwrapping fatal error in the declaration(email,first_name,last_name) NSUserdefault area.

Comment: First of all Swift is a type inferred language. It means you don't need to specify the type most of the time. You should always use String instead of NSString. You are naming your vars starting with capital letters and Swift convention is to name it starting with a lowercase letter. The same applies to your functions naming.

Comment: Nextoutlet change to nextOutlet and so on

Comment: "var Mobile_Number:NSString = mobilenumber.text as NSString" CHANGE to "var mobile_Number = mobilenumber.text" and so on